# How To Remove A Broken Program From the Programs and Features List In Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

On a Windows 7 64-bit desktop, there is a program on the Programs and Features list (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features) that refused to uninstall. The error obtained is:

```
 Error 1723. There is a problem with this Installer package.
 A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run
```

I suspect filer were deleted or corrupted. The big problem is that the program refused to install itself over the broken version.

**So how to I manually clean up the list of installed program?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends on how the program is detecting that it is already installed.

The programs showing in the Programs and Features list are generated from the registry keys under:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

The program may be looking elsewhere in the registry, or looking for a file on disk, in order to determine if it is already installed.

You can use Process Monitor (ProcMon) from Sysinternals to see which files and reg keys it is poking at when it refuses to cooperate with you.

Comment: 32 bit programs installed on a 64 bit machine will be in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` folder described by @Fabien instead.

Comment: If it was installed from a .MSI, it will also be listed under:
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products`

Comment: If the application was installed "for this user only" then its entry will be under the same path but starting at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Answer (score 33):

Microsoft makes a tool available for fixing program installation and uninstallation issues. It's available from

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

**Edit:** Microsoft seems to be trying to get rid of these "diagcab" utilities, but the replacement available from the link above does not function correctly. The original utility is available from this third-party site:

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_program_install_and_uninstall_troubleshooter.html

Because this is a third-party site, I recommend confirming that the file is signed by Microsoft Corporation on the Digital Signatures tab of the file properties before running it.

Comment: I think that service doesn't work anymore. Everytime I try to download the tool it says it can't communicate with the server.

Comment: @DonnyV: I just tried it and it downloaded fine for me. It may have been a temporary glitch. If it's still not working, try downloading the tool from a different computer (click the "Advanced-Download to run on a different or disconnected computer" link just under the "Run Now" link). Malicious software can block downloads from Microsoft (to try and prevent itself from being removed) so you may want to check for that as well.

Comment: I was unable to remove a program using the "Programs and Features" tool (appwiz.cpl), receiving an error stating "Another version of this product is already installed." The tool linked above was able to successfully remove the program. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here are two cases with a little different solution each:

1. The program (in the form of file or folder) you are trying to uninstall came with your computer upon purchase.
2. The program (file or folder) you are trying to uninstall was either you installed , installed without you knowledge by someone else.

Your strategy in both cases is:

- Reinstall the same software to make it in complete shape (a missing or corrupt file in the program won't let you uninstall).
- Reboot your computer.
- Uninstall the program.
- Reboot again.

Solution to case 1:

1. Open *Start* → *Help & Support*.
2. Type *software and hardware reinstallation* and select *software program re-installation*".
3. Follow the wizard's instructions.
4. Reboot your computer.
5. Open *Start* → *Control Panel* → *Programs & Features*
6. Locate the program you want to uninstall and right-click it with your mouse.
7. Select *Uninstall*.
8. Reboot your computer again.

Solution to case 2:

1. Visit a search engine (e.g., Google).
2. Locate the company's website where you can download exactly the same software.
3. Download and reinstall the software.
4. Reboot your computer.
5. Open *Start* → *Control Panel* → *Programs & Features*
6. Locate the program you want to uninstall and right-click it with your mouse.
7. Select *Uninstall*.
8. Reboot your computer again.

Comment: Installing again, before uninstalling worked. I'll have to remember this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think just cleaning up will not really change the problem with the program. You can try ccleaner http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/features and let it remove the list entry, but you would still want to try and clean the registry by hand. Go and look for the keys of the program in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\YourProgram or if you run a 32bit app on 64bit OS in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\YourProgram
You may try reinstall it afterwards and then cleanly uninstall.
I would suggest you let ccleaner perform a registry cleanup afterwards.

Comment: That's a neat program and I let clean out lots of things but unfortunately it failed to remove the offending program with the same error as Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Had a program where none of the above options would work.

Ended up dumping the whole registry, looking for its name in it and found it here:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

To make my life easier, just ended up using Revo Uninstaller to remove it.

Comment: Instead of Revo Uninstaller (not free), I picked a better RegEdit at http://alternativeto.net/software/regedit/ - The O&O solution was nice, and free (https://www.oo-software.com/en/ooregeditor)

Answer (score 1):

Corresponding registry keys may also be located in

```
HKEY_USERS\(user id)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

For me (user id) was `S-1-5-21-874921695-2243469788-227544040-1000`, but I'm not quite sure if it's unique or not.

Installation files may be present in `C:\Users\(user name)\AppData\Local\Package Cache`. If so, the letter-number id for searching in the registry can be found there.

Answer (score 0):

The Installer gives you a Path for the File... just pick one part of the Temp folder with the random numbers and letters and search for it in the regeditor... delete all entrys (the whole folder) that you find. I had to do it for the looks and colorista.msi so it took a few minutes

Comment: Hello and welcome to SuperUser. Do you have any source from where you can give credit to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate through the registry searching for "AppName". It will take a while, but you'll find mostly all the entries related to the program.

After that, use CCleaner to perform a registry clean. And then reinstall / uninstall (again) the app using the MSI installer file.