# Program re-install is not working after manual program deletion in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I downloaded the BlueStacks player from their [website](https://www.bluestacks.com/download.html). It was installed in my C drive (SSD) which was running out of space, so I wanted to uninstall it and re-install it in my D drive (HDD). However, the uninstall was not working, so I manually deleted the Bluestacks folder from `C:Program Files`. Now, when I am trying to run the installed again it gives me an error saying "The latest version of Bluestacks is already installed on your PC".

[image]

[image]

I tried fixing the registry using CCleaner but it did not work. Please help!

Comment: This answer could help you : https://superuser.com/questions/401511/how-to-remove-a-broken-program-from-the-programs-and-features-list-in-windows-7

Comment: I just searched for "BlueStacks" in C and deleted the every possible file.. and it worked.

Comment: You could check if the application was uninstalled successfully by run this command in PowerShell **Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name**. If it was still listed in the result, please uninstall the application via PowerShell, for more details, please refer to this article:[How To Use PowerShell To Uninstall an Application](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2019/08/27/powershell-to-uninstall-an-application.aspx). And then you could try to reinstall the specific application.

Comment: You have done enough damage (incorrect program deletion followed by registry changes) that you likely need to run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10